# xslt 1.0 how to create differentes variable inside foreach loop

Tags: xslt-1.0

i have xml source as result of sql query and i show all on browser with xsl file. Inside a for each loop i need to create dinamically a different variable for each iteration because of i have to pass this variable to javascript function to be elaborated and the result push html on a tag with ID. I don't know how to assign a correct name to the variable. I wrote this that doesn't work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Record">
  <table id="tableId-{position()}">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Testata 1</th>
        <th>Testata 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <xsl:variable name="variableN">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="testo" />
      <xsl:with-param name="replace">'</xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="by">\'</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <script>
    displayTableRowsDueColById('<xsl:value-of select="$variableN" />');
  </script>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is create a template that contains the variable and the call to your javascript function.  Pass in whatever you need for the string-replace-all. Then call the template within the script tags as follows:
(Sample code not tested.)

```
<xsl:for-each select="Record">
  <table id="tableId-{position()}">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Testata 1</th>
        <th>Testata 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
     <xsl:call-template name="callDisplayTable">
       <xsl:with-param name="text" select=" <Put some value here> "/>
     </xsl:call-template>
  </script>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:template name="callDisplayTable">
  <xsl:param name="text"/>

  <xsl:variable name="variableN">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text" />
      <xsl:with-param name="replace">'</xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="by">\'</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>

  displayTableRowsDueColById('<xsl:value-of select="$variableN" />');

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you @Bluewood66  but could you write some lines of example? my problem is to have n variables with different name ( n = records)

Comment: I'm not quite clear about the n variables.  Hopefully, the code I added  eliminates the need for n variables.  Just make sure you put a value where the codes says <Put some value here>.